# Stuck with tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making an app with dynamic tables inside of it. I had managed to let it work with the table inside the MainviewController, but now i am stuck. I tried to put the table code in its own class. 
strange thing is that it gives no errors. 
This is what i do:
MainviewController.m:

```
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 0;//0 will later be i
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size.width = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;

TellerTable *tellerTable = [[TellerTable alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

[tellerTable loadWithJsonData:JSONArray];
[tellerTable setDataSource:tellerTable];


[self.view addSubview:tellerTable];
[tellerTable reloadData];
```

TableTeller.m:

```
-(void)loadWithJsonData:(NSArray *)JA
{
   self.JSONArray = JA;
   tableview = self;

   self.delegate = self;
   self.dataSource = self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSMutableArray *TellerItems = [JSONArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return TellerItems.count;
}
```

(the rest to make the table cellForRowAtIndexPath etc..)
TellerTable.h

```
@interface TellerTable : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UITableView *tableview;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSArray *JSONArray;
    -(void)loadWithJsonData:(NSArray *)JA;
@end
```

Strange thing is, it goes to loadwithJSON, then it calls numberOfRowsInSection but after that it stops. It doesn't add the table to the scrollview. What am i doeing wrong/forget?

Comment: Check whether `TellerItems.count;` is zero

Comment: Is the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` returning zero (0)? If so, none of the other delegate methods are invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your approach .. you have created a subclass of UITableView and then another tableView property on the same then you are assigning it to self all feels wrong even if it works. I dont see any use of subclassing here you are not customising the table so why are you subclassing it?. Add a tableView(drag and drop) to xib or storyboard then connect outlet to mainviewcontroller. You may be able to make it work somehow using this method but its errorprone,less readable etc etc

Comment: I need to add a x tables in a pageControl. thats why i add them dynamicly.